# setprecision equivalent in C#?

Tags: c#

In C++ I would do:

```
auto loadingTime = TimeUtilities::getDistance<milliseconds_t>(TimeUtilities::getNow(), startTime);
std::cout << "Reset all accounts and players in " << std::setprecision(3) << loadingTime / 1000.f << " seconds!" << std::endl << std::endl;
```

However in C# I tried to do something similar, but it failed:

```
double loadingTime = TimeUtil.GetDistanceInMilliseconds(DateTime.Now, startTime);

Console.WriteLine("Reset all accounts and characters in {0:0.000} seconds!", loadingTime);
```

The Method `GetDistanceInMilliseconds` just returns the `TotalMilliseconds` value of the `TimeSpan` between the two `DateTime` objects.

How can I do mimic the same behavior in C#?

**EDIT:** Dividing the value by `1000f` will work if the `loadingTime` value is less than 1 second. If it's more than 1 second, the displayed value will be wrong.

My goal is to display a loading time from the start point to the end point (`DateTime.Now` is the start point and `startTime` is the end point) in milliseconds (up to 3 decimal points).

Comment: Can you show the output of the C++ code agains the output of the C# code?

Comment: @Steve The output is the same, the values aren't. In the C++ code it shows the correct value, but in the C# code it shows 7.000 seconds, which should be 0.007. So I added /1000f to the value, but that broke it.

Comment: The output is in milliseconds so if you want the seconds you should divide by 1000. What has been broken by the division?

Answer (score 0):

Use `0.###` specifier:

```
7d.ToString("0.###", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

returns `7`,

```
0.007d.ToString("0.###", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

returns `0.007`